# How to parse JSON response from API

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to fetch json data and put it in a ListView. I was following a tutorial and tried to implement this. Problem is: the tutorial was based on `AppCompatActivity` and I am trying to add it in a `Fragment` (Tab):

```
public class InstallsTab extends Fragment{
    ListView installs;
    String url = "http://localhost/android.php";
    ProgressBar dialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.installs_tab, container, false);

        installs = rootView.findViewById(R.id.install_list);

        dialog = new ProgressBar(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String string) {
                parseJsonData(string);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        rQueue.add(request);

        return rootView;
    }

    void parseJsonData(String jsonString) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray fruitsArray = object.getJSONArray("fruits");
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

            for(int i = 0; i < fruitsArray.length(); ++i) {
                al.add(fruitsArray.getString(i));
            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
            installs.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

[image]

And the app is crashing on run.

Comment: share error logcat..

Comment: Please debug code and get crashing point or share LogCat

Comment: add your response in your question.

Comment: share error that is coming

Comment: @user3449848 please check my updated ans.

Comment: use getActivity() only to pass the context to adapter and try.

Comment: Next time you can try Moshi or Gson if you want to avoid manual parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not initialize your array list proper

Use this

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Instead of this

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

**EDIT**

also change this  use **`i++`** instead of **`++i`**

```
for(int i = 0; i < fruitsArray.length(); i++) {

    al.add(fruitsArray.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: While your version is better this does not explain a crash.

Comment: With your reference warning on `el.add` is gone. what about `new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);` ? can i get out of it?

Comment: Use Like this ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
            installs.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @user3449848 Happy to help you. Happy coding.

Comment: You guys are very helpful. I wouldn't learn anything properly without your help. Specially thanks to stackoverflow.com